# sed word boundary not working with colon character

Tags: sed

I have the following file

```
> cat tmp
"aaa"
"aaa:xyz"
```

The desired output is

```
"bbb"
"aaa:xyz"
```

I'm using the following sed command

```
sed "s/\baaa\b/bbb/" tmp
```

But with this command, I get

```
"bbb"
"bbb:xyz"
```

The colon character is considered as word boundary it seems. How can I get the desired output where only the first line gets changed and not the 2nd line? I even tried the following but it had no effect

```
sed "s/\Baaa\B/bbb/" tmp
sed "s/\baaa\B/bbb/" tmp
sed "s/\Baaa\b/bbb/" tmp
```

Edit:
I have to use other sed commands on the same file like this

```
's/aaa:xyz/ttt/' tmp
```

So, I can't do substitution only if there's no colon. I should be able to do substitution regardless of colons being present in the line

Comment: I tried this it didn't work
`
sed "s/\baaa$/bbb/" tmp
Illegal variable name.
sed "s/\baaa\$/bbb/" tmp
Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.
`

Comment: `sed 's/^aaa$/bbb/' file`?

Comment: This had no effect @Cyrus

Comment: @Arteezy: You don't seem to test it with your shown example.

Comment: @Cyrus, so sorry. I updated the question. There are double quotes around the word. Without the quotes yes your solution worked

Comment: Please try to clarify *exactly* what you want.  Apparently you want `aaa` to be considered a “word” in the context `"aaa"` (with literal quotes in the text) but not `"aaa:xyz"`.  What about `"123:aaa"`, `'aaa'`, `'aaa:xyz'`, `(aaa)`, `The quick aaa fox` or `jumps over the lazy aaa.` (with a literal period in the text)? Don’t answer just for these six examples; give a general explanation. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU `\b` zero-width word-boundary pattern matches between a word-character and a non-word character.  A "word character" is generally any alphanumeric character, and underscore (`_`).  This means that `\b` would match between `aaa` and `:` in the string `aaa:`.

The following illustrates where `\b` matches in your example document, by replacing all matches of `\b` with `*`:

```bsh
$ sed 's/\b/*/g' file
"*aaa*"
"*aaa*:*xyz*"
```

To replace all instances of `"aaa"` with `"bbb"`, use

```bsh
$ sed 's/"aaa"/"bbb"/g' file
"bbb"
"aaa:xyz"
```

To replace all *words* `aaa` with `bbb` on any line not containing a colon:

```bsh
$ sed '/:/!s/\baaa\b/bbb/g' file
"bbb"
"aaa:xyz"
```

To replace all words `aaa` that are followed by something that is not a colon, with `bbb`:

```bsh
$ sed -e 's/\baaa\([^:]\)/bbb\1/g' -e 's/\baaa$/bbb/' file
"bbb"
"aaa:xyz"
```

Note that the first substitution here *requires* that the `aaa` substring *is* followed by another character.  This means that the `aaa` substring would not be replaced at the extreme end of the line. This is why we do a separate substitution for that case.

Answer (score 1):

If doesn't match `:` replace aaa with bbb:

```
sed '/:/! s/aaa/bbb/g' test.txt
```

With perl:

```
perl -pe 'if(!/:/){s/aaa/bbb/}' tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Can you explain please this part `/:/!`

Comment: Is it possible to do this without checking for `:` match? I have other sed commands like `sed 's/aaa:xyz/ttt/'` to be used on the same file. So I can't use this particular way

Comment: The character `!` is a negation of the match `/:/`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed 's/"aaa"/"bbb"/' file
```

Output:

```
"bbb"
"aaa:xyz"
```

Comment: I believe that you’re missing the point of the question.  But I concede that the question is somewhat unclear.  On the other hand, I believe that you’re focusing on answering the example and not on answering the question.  Read the question *title* again.  Do you believe that `sed '1s/aaa/bbb/'` would be a correct answer to the question?